# Why would PHP report errors in my Include that aren't really errors?

Tags: php

Warning: include(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\happyDB\script\logincheck.php on line 3

The funny thing is, is its working fine and the file its saying isn't there is... Any ideas?

Comment: php is very fault tollerant, if it can continue to parse the script despite an included file being missing it will do so. Find and remove the offending include if it is not required

Comment: that's not an error. it's a WARNING. since it's just an include, failing to load the file is NOT an error.

Comment: my include is required... its pointing to my config file. Why would it pass me a warning when the file is clearly there. My config file has all of my php configurations for my app.

Comment: _“when the file is clearly there”_ – well, PHP seems to have a different opinion on that than you do … and what is the exact path to that file in your file system?

Comment: If my config was in the wrong place, the app wouldnt work. Its working fine but giving me the warning.

Comment: Please tell us the full file system path of your config file.

Comment: You can use require or require_once instead of include. That way PHP will stop if the file is not found.

Comment: include('../config.php');

Comment: \*sigh* … I am not asking about the PHP code you are using to include the file (that we already know), but what the full path to the file in your file system is … so something like `C:\wamp\www\…`

Comment: Yes, the path to config.php would help.

Comment: C:\wamp\www\happyDB\config.php

Comment: And what is `include_path` set to in your PHP config? (Use f.e. `phpinfo()` to find out.)

Comment: require breaks my app... but when i use include again it works with no problem with error_reporting turned off.

Comment: If require breaks your app, then config.php is not being loaded when using includes.

Comment: How do you run the PHP script? logincheck.php directly from the browser?

Comment: im running my app locally at the moment.

Comment: Does require 'C:\wamp\www\happyDB\config.php'; work ?

Comment: hmmm.. just tried that. still says it doesn't exist.

Comment: phpinfo - include_path: .;C:\php\pear .;C:\php\pear @CBroe

Comment: Can you open "C:\wamp\www\happyDB\config.php" in a program like a text editor ? If your using linux or something like that you need to use the right case. Maybe its C:\WAMP\WWW\happyDB\config.php or something like that ?

Comment: When i put that in my local browser it works just fine... C:\wamp\www\happyDB\config.php - i can see my config file. I am using Windows.

Comment: How about require_once 'c:/wamp/www/happyDB/config.php'; ?

Comment: First of all - if the script still worked, you should have had included (successfully) config.php before (you said it was needed). That is why I asked you how did you run logincheck.php - is it being included or is it the URL you use to access the page? Also, have a look at other files you might include.

Comment: @scootergrisen BINGO!!!!! that worked... wonder why 'require' doesn't work and 'include' gives error.

Comment: If you change what @scootergrisen gave you for a require, it gives you an error? So it was changing \ into / . Nice catch.

Comment: require_once seems to work but require does not.

Comment: and it only works with the absolute path and not the ../config.php one.

Comment: It must be because config.php is included multiple times in your code. Thats why we have _once to make sure it doesnt get included more then once by mistake. It can get confusing when you inlcude files that include other files.

Comment: its only included 1 time and thats inside of the file i referenced in my question. It isnt included anywhere else. However, I am referencing the logincheck.php on several pages. Perhaps thats it... i dont know but its working as expected and the warnings are gone. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's configured to do so in the php.ini file.

> PHP 5.3 or later, the default value is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED. This setting does not show E_NOTICE, E_STRICT and E_DEPRECATED level errors. You may want to show them during development. Prior to PHP 5.3.0, the default value is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT. In PHP 4 the default value is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE.

Have a look at the PHP docs to see how to modify the situations in which PHP reports errors.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: Well, this i know... but why would it pass a warning when the file is clearly there?

Comment: I am able to turn error reporting off of course, but i was curious why its fussing about my include and its clearly there. without it, my app wont work.

Comment: The error means: in the file `C:\wamp\www\happyDB\script\logincheck.php`, there is an error in your line 3: you've included `C:\wamp\www\happyDB\config.php` when actually it didn't exist. Are you sure "config.php" is not inside the "script" folder? Else, make sure login.php is not being included from another directory or you've done anything to change the current working directory. - Another option is that maybe the warnings are old, and you've already solved the problem (since you say it works). Are there recent warnings?

Comment: but it does exist. if it didnt, my app would never work. This controls my login session.